# How do I create a generic Cuboid class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, class, generics

I am being asked to create a generic Cuboid class that stores three dimensions of a cuboid. I have to add methods to set and get the length, breadth, and height. Next, add a method public String toString() that will return all for the dimensions.

I created my class in Eclipse.

```
public class CuboidDimensions <T> {


}
```

I have two questions about this exercise.

1) Does the Cuboid generic class need public static void main(String [] args)? Why or why not? (I really don't understand this.)

2) How do I write the methods to set and get the three dimensions listed above?

I am still having a hard time understanding Java period. I am not a huge fan of Eclipse. I prefer Netbeans, but I have to use Eclipse for my class.

Comment: By being asked to create a generic Cuboid class i think you have to deal with inheritance and not java generics.

Comment: 1) As your class will represent an object, there's  no need for a "main" method. You can create a specific class with this method in order to make some tests on your Cuboid class
2) In Eclise, you can right-click => source => generate getters and setters

Comment: Eclipse is just an IDE. It has nothing to do with the code you're writing. You could write the same thing in Notepad and compile it on the command line with the compiler include in the JDK.

Comment: "I have two questions about this exercise" then ask your teacher/professor etc.

Comment: I have asked my professor in the past. I was given the answer key. While having the answer key is nice to complete a task, I still didn't understand what I was doing or why I was doing it. That is why I asked here. I truly want to understand.

Comment: Well StackOverflow isn't really suited to that kind of question. It's way too broad. You'll be much better off going through a thorough set of tutorials aimed at beginners. [The Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) are a good place to start. Consider raising the issue with your professor, or go above their head, if you're not getting the support you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your 'CuboidDimensions' class will need a 'main(String [] args)' method if it is the class that you are using to run the program. The 'main()' method is where your Java program will run from, and is the one that calls/ creates all of the objects used when the program loads. If your application is being run from another class, (i.e. one of your other classes has a 'main()' method), then your 'CuboidDimensions' class will not need a 'main()' method.

2) Your set methods will be written something like:

```
public void setLength(float length){
    this.length = length; //or whatever- you probably actually want to assign it to some user input taken from the keyboard?
}
```

3) Your get methods will be written something like:

```
public float getLength(){
    return length;
}
```

You'll obviously need global variables declared in your class for each of the dimensions to do it like this.

Comment: Your set method is confusing. You're not assigning to any field of the class. You're also ignoring whatever argument is passed in. I'd expect it to look like `public void setLength(float length) { this.length = length; }`

Comment: You are right re assigning the `length` variable- answer updated. However, I mentioned in the last sentence of my answer that there would need to be global variables declared in the class to do this. The OP hasn't shown any of the implementation of their class, so we don't know what variables they have declared...

Comment: There's no such thing as globals in Java. You mean a field. And even if the field had existed, your set method wouldn't have worked because the parameter would be [shadowing the field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). But all is good now :)

Comment: Thank you for the help... I didn't realize I had to declare variables first. I declared my three variables and have my set/get methods. I honestly learned a lot from asking on here. I realize this isn't the best place, but I was so frustrated. I really do appreciate your help and insight.

Comment: A global variable in Java is a variable that is declared within the scope of a class, but outside any methods- i.e. it is global because it is accessible by all methods within that class. A local variable is one declared within the scope of a method- i.e. it is local because it is only accessible within that particular method.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse writes the methods to set and get by himself. Just go to Source - Generate Getters and Setters

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!